# Switching from General to Specific in Maximum Likelihood Estimation: Why Use $y_i$​ Instead of $a$?

Tags: probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood

I've been working through a statistical model that utilizes both the cumulative distribution function (CDF) and the probability density function (PDF) to describe the behavior of a variable $y_i$ conditional on another variable $x_i$, along with parameters $\beta$ and $\sigma$. The model is described as follows:

CDF of $y_i$ is given as a conditional probability $\operatorname{Pr}\left(y_i^* \leqslant a \mid y_i^*<c\right)$ for $a<c$, expressed by:
$$
\operatorname{Pr}\left(y_i \leqslant a\right)=\frac{\Phi\left(\frac{a-x_i^{\prime} \beta}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{c-x_i^{\prime} \beta}{\sigma}\right)} .
$$

1. PDF of $y_i$, derived from the CDF, is:
   $$
   p_{y_i}(a)=\frac{\partial \operatorname{Pr}\left(y_i \leqslant a\right)}{\partial a}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sigma} \phi\left(\frac{a-x_i^{\prime} \beta}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{c-x_i^{\prime} \beta}{\sigma}\right)} .
   $$

When transitioning to estimation through maximum likelihood, the likelihood and loglikelihood are defined as:
$$
\begin{gathered}
L(\beta, \sigma)=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\frac{1}{\sigma} \phi\left(\frac{y_i-x_i^{\prime} \beta}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{c-x_i^{\prime} \beta}{\sigma}\right)} \\
\ln L(\beta, \sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left\{-\ln (\sigma)+\ln \left[\phi\left(\frac{y_i-x_i^{\prime} \beta}{\sigma}\right)\right]-\ln \left[\Phi\left(\frac{c-x_i^{\prime} \beta}{\sigma}\right)\right]\right\} .
\end{gathered}
$$

My question centers on the shift from using an arbitrary constant $a$ in the definitions of the CDF and PDF to using the observed values $y_i$ in the likelihood and loglikelihood functions. Specifically:

- Why is $y_i$ used instead of $a$ in the output of the likelihood and loglikelihood functions?
- What is the significance of using in the context of these equations?

I understand that the shift reflects moving from a theoretical description of the distribution to applying the model to observed data. However, I would appreciate further insights into the mathematical or statistical reasoning behind this choice, especially regarding the implications for maximum likelihood estimation.